# Scrapy isn't finding any links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this website (http://www.healthspace.ca/Clients/VIHA/VIHA_Website.nsf/), however, scrapy doesn't seem to be able to find the links on any of the pages.

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: inspection_grabber)
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'inspection_grabber.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['inspection_grabber.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'inspection_grabber'}
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.healthspace.ca/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.healthspace.ca/Clients/VIHA/VIHA_Website.nsf/> (referer: None)
http://www.healthspace.ca/Clients/VIHA/VIHA_Website.nsf/
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 472,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1360,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 19, 53, 1, 822353),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 19, 53, 1, 522968)}
2016-11-17 11:53:01 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "first"
    allowed_domains = ["www.healthspace.ca"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.healthspace.ca/Clients/VIHA/VIHA_Website.nsf/']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['.*']),
            callback='parse',
            follow=True 
        )
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Comment: That page contains no links.  It has _frames_, which themselves contain links, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnGordon What about this page? (http://healthspace.ca/Clients/VIHA/VIHA_Website.nsf/Food-List-ByName?OpenView&RestrictToCategory=0c8f6f469d6a3e56964b3a748cb4dd94&count=30&start=1) It is still unable to detect any of the links.

Comment: That page appears to have lots of links.  (Why did you have to ask me? Aren't you able to view the source of a page yourself?)

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm asking because for whatever reason Scrapy isn't able to detect the links and thus doesn't follow them as it should.

Comment: As a very first debugging step, surely you're able to view the page source yourself to perhaps see _why_ scrapy is having trouble?

Comment: Your link extractor works fine for me on that 2nd URL you shared: http://pastebin.com/2WnBHEmu

Comment: Also , you need to use `CrawlSpider` as the parent class, i.e. `class FirstSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider)`. The plain `scrapy.Spider` does not understand `rules` attribute

Comment: LinkExtractor outputs aboslute links.

Comment: @paultrmbrth That worked, thanks!